# Google play services ads SDK is too big that causing over 64K methods

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

I am using   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0

is there any way to use this google play dependency and can run into the 64K reference limit?

I have used that dependency before and i have never got multidex errors(# methods: 66043 > 65536) but why on this app in which i have lesser dependencies than other apps.

> App1: This app is with over 64K methods

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
}
```

App2: But this app work fine with same google play service dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lite version of the ads dependency that is much smaller than the full version and can help you stay under the 64K limit:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:19.5.0'
```

You can find more information about it here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/lite-sdk